# Understanding「そのあと」as the object of 「埋める」 in this sentence?

Tags: demonstratives, object

I am currently reading 《ノルウェイの森》

And there is a sentence that I am quite confused about:

> 体の中の何かが欠落して、**そのあと**を埋めるものもないまま、それは純粋な空洞として放置されていた。

I think 欠落する can be treated as lacking of something and 埋める as compensating something.
And thus, the object of verb 埋める seems weird to me, because it should compensate for that thing that is lacked. I think そのあと should act like a abverbial of time. So that clause can be translated as

> After that, there is nothing for compensation

and in this translation, I find it hard to choose an object for the verb compensate. So I just use the noun form.

Also, this is my first time asking question. Any suggestion for improving this question will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read it as その跡, not その後 as a temporal expression.

跡, which I guess is from the same origin as 後, means a trace or mark left by something that was there but no longer exists.

欠落 is used as an action verb (like "to drop") here. When that happened, what was left behind was a hole or gap because 何か was *inside* the body (体の中). This makes その跡 (literally "its trace") a natural direct object for 埋める ("to fill").

Answer (score 1):

そのあと here means 'the space/void/blank **after that**(=なにか) is gone'.

Probably it helps to think 欠落する as somewhat more active *to drop off* than static *to be lacking*. Literally: *Something dropped off from the body, there was nothing to fill the space occupied by that, and it just remained as a hole.*